# Ruby on Rails: Create multiple records with multiple files uploaded at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I've created a Rails app using ActiveStorage that can upload multiple small video files into one record. My model is 'clip' and I'm currently uploading multiple videos files to one clip record.

I have this in the clip model:

```
has_many_attached :videos
```

This in the controller's private params.

```
def clip_params
  params.require(:clip).permit(:name, :duration, videos: [])
end
```

And this in the form to upload the videos.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :videos %>
  <%= form.file_field :videos, multiple: true %>
</div>
```

It works fine and the videos are uploading to the one record. However, what I need to do is -- upon upload of multiple files -- create a separate record for each of the video files uploaded. Of course I can do this one at a time by uploading one file each time, but I'd like to be able to upload multiple files at once (e.g. 15 small video files), and have my app create a separate record for each video uploaded -- so multiple clips each with an attached video. I'm assuming I can use a Clip.create in a loop somewhere (maybe the model) but not sure where to begin. Any ideas?

Comment: Just try to define `multipart: true` in the form it self.
eg:- 
`<%= form_for @clip, multipart: true do |form|%>`

Comment: Thanks, Tashi. I tried that but unfortunately it does not seem to do anything in this case. After I make the change you suggest, my app still uploads the videos to one record only.

Comment: If the previous solution doesn't work, then other option is to add same file upload tag multiple times either on button click or define certain number of static tag. 
eg:- `(1..5).each {|i| <%= form.file_field :videos, multiple: true %> }`

Comment: Thanks again, Tashi. I figured out what I want to do by following this source using the Carrierwave gem and nested models: https://kolosek.com/carrierwave-upload-multiple-images/.

Comment: Glad that you are able to solve the issue.